# how to change the image of a particular row in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with each row having an image and an image button. When ever we click on that button it should  pick an image from image gallery from the device and should replace the image of that particular row.

I can able to pick the image from gallery but it is replacing the image of last row instead of
replacing the image of the row from where we pressed the button.

Please provide me some solution for this

Here I'm attaching the code

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
String[] names;
CustomAdapter adapter;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
ListView lv;
int a;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    Resources res = getResources();
    names = res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, names);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void removeAtomPayOnClickHandler(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      a=lv.getPositionForView(lv);
      Toast.makeText(this, "---"+a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
         CHolder.tv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
      //  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }


}
```

}

and the code for adapter class

```
      public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
      Context context;
      String[] input;
      public CustomAdapter(Context c, String[] values) {
    super(c, R.layout.atom_pay_list_item, values);
    this.context = c;
    this.input = values;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;
    CHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atom_pay_list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new CHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (CHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    //holder.tv.setImageDrawable(drawable)(input[position]);
    ///iv.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_search);
    return row;
}
static class CHolder{
    public static ImageView tv;
    public static ImageButton iv;
    CHolder(View v)
    {
        tv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        iv = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actual adapter, you could add a click listener to your image and then manipulate it from there. For example,

in getView()

```
if(row == null){
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atom_pay_list_item, parent, false);
     holder = new CHolder(row);
     row.setTag(holder);

     // Add this in
     iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
              v.setImageResource(R.id.new_image_id);
              // could obviously be more complex, like your  onActivityResult() functionality
         }
     }
}
...

return row;
```

If you need the click to register in your receiver, you could send a broadcast to your activity. In other words, instead of `v.setImageResource(R.id.new_image_id);`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("UPDATE_IMAGE");
intent.putExtra("clicked_position", position);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And then in your activity, after putting `registerReceiver, new UpdateReceiver(), new IntentFilter("UPDATE_IMAGE");` in your onCreate method of your activity.

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.getExtra("clicked_position", -1);
        int positioin = intent.getExtras().getInt("clicked_position", -1);
        // do what you need to with your clicked image given its position
        // basically do onActivityResult() functionality here
    }
}
```

Just make sure to unregister your receiver in onDestroy of your activity to avoid leaks.